# iphone xcode 5 app iOS

Tags: iphone

How I can save  value in TextField  for showing after closing and opening app?

self.suma.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [self.a1.text intValue]+[self.a2.text intValue]];

I want to do it with "suma".

Answer (score 2):

See documentation for [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

// Write
[defaults setObject:self.suma.text forKey:@"suma"];

// Read
self.suma.text = [defaults stringForKey:@"suma"];
```